# How to update ag grid row cells custom components properties based on redux store data update

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i have ag grid component and it contains some custom components like progress bar.

i have the socket connection and it will updates the socket data in reducer for every second.

i tried with rowNode.setDataValue, but it creating an issues like entire component dom was updating and it was blinking on the browser ui while updating the socket data.

But it working fine while i connect progress bar directly to reducer and using the socket data.

Can some one help me out ,Thanks is advance